# No internet access on startup of app

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

My app makes a network call for data at the startup of app. The network call is made in `viewDidLoad`. I'm using **Reachability** class to detect the internet availability before making the call. Sometimes (most of times) it give me no internet access right away.

I'm unable to understand what are the assumptions of iOS on this subject. i.e Apps are stalled for sometime till they are allotted internet access etc. What happens in the background? I have seen many apps which achieve the same functionality without any major errors. What are they doing what I'm missing. What are the general approaches for the same problem on other platforms as well? (Android etc.)

Comment: I don't understand what it is your asking. Yes user may sometimes not have an internet connection. If its needed, either load a cache, no cache available, pop up a message of some sort. Whats the issue?

Comment: There is no such thing as delayed internet allotment. All third party apps are treated as equal in the democracy of iPhone apps. 
There must be something in the implementation of your reachability class, or you may check in other devices.

Comment: Ohh This is so embarrassing. I was starting the notifier (Reachability Notifier) on a background thread. Really don't know how I overlooked on this for 3 months.